# Looking for short story where politicians are drafted

Tags: story-identification, short-stories

I remember reading this at least a decade or more ago, most likely in one of the short story periodicals like Asimov's or Analog... The president is drafted (selected by computer algorithm?) to serve a short term and there is a competition to be the programmer who supplies the analysis/advisory software.

Comment: So not Franchise (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Franchise_(short_story)#:~:text=%22Franchise%22)?

Comment: No, not "Franchise". In the story I'm looking for, the programmer and his program are in a competition to become the "analyst" for the newly-drafted President.